# remove quotes in post values based on array key name

Tags: php, arrays, post

I want to be able to remove quotations from a field on or abouts the name of 'quote'. On post, all my field names and values get matched up and put into an array then enter to the database. Before the SQL is built and after I build the value-key array, how can I single out the field quote, remove the quotation marks that the user inputted, and then add/keep the content in the `$values` array for my SQL? The questionable area starts with the comment "remove quotes"

```
public function insertIntoDb($table, $carryUrl = NULL, $ext = '')
{
    if (in_array($table, $this->disallow_insert)) {
        self::show_error("Inserting into the table '{$table}' is not possible, check the configuration file if this is an error.");
    } elseif (!isset($table)) {
        self::show_error('Missing `table` parameter in ' . __FUNCTION__);
    }
    $resultInsert = Nemesis::query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$table}");
    if (!$resultInsert) {
        self::show_error(QUERY_ERROR);
    }
    $fieldnames = array();
    if ($resultInsert->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $resultInsert->fetch_array()) {
            $fieldnames[] = $row['Field'];
            $values = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($fieldnames));
            // $values = array_filter($values, function($x) { return $x !== ''; });
            // <5.3 $values = array_filter($values, create_function('$x', 'return $x !== "";'));
        }
    }
    // remove quotes for testimonials
    if (array_key_exists('quote', array_change_key_case($values, CASE_LOWER))) {

        $values['quote'] = preg_replace("/<!--.*?-->/", "", $values); // remove quotes

    }
    // filter the array
    $values = self::filter($values);
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (created, created_by, %s) VALUES (NOW(), '$_SESSION[user_id]', '%s')", $table, implode(', ', array_keys($values)), implode("', '", $values));
    if ($this->debug) {
        echo '<p>' . $sql . '</p>';
    } elseif (Nemesis::query($sql)) {
        $msg = new Messages();
        $msg->add('s', QUERY_INSERT_SUCCESS);
        if ($table == 'projects') {
            $msg = new Messages();
            $msg->add('s', "Information was added to the database. Time to add images!");
        }
        if (!is_null($carryUrl) && isset($carryUrl)) {
            redirect($carryUrl . '?id=' . $_POST['id'] . '&table=' . $table . $ext);
        }
    } else {
        self::show_error(QUERY_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: So all you're asking for is: Strip quotes (this ones -> '' AND? this ones -> "") ?

Comment: I don't understand your regex...that doesn't remove quotes.  Try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) is a function that returns a value, not a void.  You'll need to assign the returned value back to `$values['quote']`:

```
// remove quotes for testimonials
if (array_key_exists('quote', array_change_key_case($values, CASE_LOWER))) {

    $values['quote'] = preg_replace("/(\"|')/", "", $values['quote']); // remove quotes

}
```

Comment: understandable, but this only returns a value of `array` for the quote field: `if (array_key_exists('quote', array_change_key_case($values, CASE_LOWER))) { 
   $values['quote'] = preg_replace("/<!--.*?-->/", "", $values); // remove quotes
  }`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  What values are you trying to "return"? Is `$values['quote']` an array but you need it to be string?

Comment: all the values get entered into a value key array, at which point I want to essentially "filter" one value for quotes, and have the value-key array stay in the same format to be entered into the sql. Right now, if I just return the sql, every value is entered except for the `quote` which has a value of `Array` using the method you suggested.

Comment: Please look at my solution more closely.  I am specifying a specific field in the array.  You are not.

Comment: Right, so within the confines of my above "problem" where does this fit in?

Comment: Edited answer for context.

Comment: oh sorry, the problem was with the `preg_replace` being my original way and different from the one you posted, it works now!